# Filter 2d array so that columns containing only empty values are removed from all rows

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I am looking for a way to filter a PHP multidimensional array (it is a table).
The array looks similar to this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Standort' => '',
    'Letzte Meldung' => '',
    'On-/Offline seit' => '04.05.2022 11:03',
    'Online' => '',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Standort' => 'Schweiz',
    'Letzte Meldung' => '',
    'On-/Offline seit' => '11.02.2022 14:59',
    'Online' => '',
  ),
)
```

The keys inside the array are identical each time. My goal is to loop through each sub array and remove any key that is empty in each sub array.
I have tried it with this:

```
$table_row_array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $table_row_array));
```

however that's not the solution, because then sometimes my tablerows just don't have a matching key.

The expected result would be:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Standort' => '',
    'On-/Offline seit' => '04.05.2022 11:03',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Standort' => 'Schweiz',
    'On-/Offline seit' => '11.02.2022 14:59',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Can you please show your input data in the form of a `var_export($table_row_array)` output, that gives us code we can copy&paste directly to work with.

Comment: Is it always the same keys you want to keep, or can they differ?

Comment: I will try to update the array as requested. 
The keys can be different depending on the data loaded into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the keys of your first array element. For each key, use array_values to extract all the values under that key, make them unique, and then check if there is only one left, and it is an empty string - if so, you have found a key that needs to be removed.
Afterwards, loop over the full array, and unset those keys from the individual items.

```
$data = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Standort' => '',
    'Letzte Meldung' => '',
    'On-/Offline seit' => '04.05.2022 11:03',
    'Online' => '',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Standort' => 'Schweiz',
    'Letzte Meldung' => '',
    'On-/Offline seit' => '11.02.2022 14:59',
    'Online' => '',
  ),
);

$emptyKeys = [];
foreach(array_keys($data[0]) as $key) {
    $uniqueValues = array_unique(array_column($data, $key));
    if(count($uniqueValues) == 1 && $uniqueValues[0] === '') {
        $emptyKeys[] = $key;
    }
}
foreach($emptyKeys as $emptyKey) {
    foreach($data as &$item) { // pass $item by reference here, so that we
                               // manipulate the original array, and not just a copy
        unset($item[$emptyKey]); // remove the key
    }
    unset($item); // unset the reference itself
}

var_dump($data);
```

You can of course also nest the loops, and do away with the extra `$emptyKeys` array:

```
foreach(array_keys($data[0]) as $key) {
    $uniqueValues = array_unique(array_column($data, $key));
    if(count($uniqueValues) == 1 && $uniqueValues[0] === '') {
        foreach($data as &$item) {
            unset($item[$key]);
        }
        unset($item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

switch keys and values with array_flip, unset empty one, will only work with different values in one array as similar values will be overwritten:

```
$laData = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Standort' => '',
    'Letzte Meldung' => '',
    'On-/Offline seit' => '04.05.2022 11:03',
    'Online' => '',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Standort' => 'Schweiz',
    'Letzte Meldung' => '',
    'On-/Offline seit' => '11.02.2022 14:59',
    'Online' => '',
  ),
);

$laResult = array();
foreach($laData as $laSingleData) {
    $laSingleData = array_flip($laSingleData);
    unset($laSingleData['']);
    $laSingleData = array_flip($laSingleData);
    $laResult[] = $laSingleData;
}

print_r($laResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = [
    [
        'Standort'         => '',
        'Letzte Meldung'   => '',
        'On-/Offline seit' => '04.05.2022 11:03',
        'Online'           => '',
    ],
    [
        'Standort'         => 'Schweiz',
        'Letzte Meldung'   => '',
        'On-/Offline seit' => '11.02.2022 14:59',
        'Online'           => '',
    ]
];

$keys = array_filter(
    array_keys($input[0]),
    fn($key) => array_filter(array_column($input, $key), fn($value) => !empty($value))
);

$result = array_map(
    fn($item) => array_values(array_intersect_key($item, array_flip($keys))),
    $input
);

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 04.05.2022 11:03
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Schweiz
            [1] => 11.02.2022 14:59
        )

)
```

Comment: See also: https://3v4l.org/4XI1m

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend @FatFreddy's approach that leverages `array_flip()` -- this technique can destroy values that should not be destroyed.

To add another viable solution, I'll show a couple of loops -- one to filter and one to transpose.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/L9liR))

```
$columns = [];
foreach ($input[0] as $columnName => $value) {
    $columnData = array_column($input, $columnName);
    if (strlen(implode($columnData))) {
        $columns[$columnName] = $columnData;
    }
}
$result = [];
foreach ($columns as $colName => $colValues) {
    foreach ($colValues as $i => $value) {
        $result[$i][$colName] = $value;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

For a functional style approach, iterate each leafnode in the array and collect the column names which relate to any non-empty value.  Then make another pass over the input to filter each row's contents by the whitelisted column names.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NmK3V))

```
$keep = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $input,
    function($v, $k) use(&$keep) {
        if (strlen($v)) {
            $keep[$k] = null;
        }
    }
);

var_export(
    $keep ? array_map(fn($row) => array_intersect_key($row, $keep), $input) : []
);
```